# Linux that is just a RDP client

Tags: linux, boot, remote-desktop

Is there any RDP clients i can boot from a pendrive, what I means is have Linux that boots up and is only a RDPclient nothing else, like no desktop etc.

Comment: I don't think any exist like that out of the box.  Are you against rolling your own?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is a Thin Client, that is what I've seen them refered to across multiple projects and people like HP who sell machines with this.

Any Linux OS that will run / fit on a pen drive will be able to do this. And there are lot of tutorials to do this with your favorite distribution. You can even set it up so that a basic X11 loads with rdesktop already connecting and maximized to the window.

Here is a Linux [Pendrive site](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/) - Here is a neat project [LTSP](http://www.ltsp.org/), it runs a linux over a network machine. And here is a project that seems to do exactly what you want (along with some other remote protocols) [Thinstation](http://www.thinstation.org/)

Comment: Thanks, thinstation is exactly what I'm looking for. A little bit of a side note, is there a way to browse the internet on the local machine, so that things like videos are normal quality?

Comment: Yes, they have a Firefox 3 package for thinkstation 2.x. It was posted as a news item on May 11,09.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use any of the many tiny Linuxes (e.g. [Puppy Linux](http://www.puppylinux.com/)) and just run RDP?

If you prefer to roll your own distro, [this tutorial](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1201273) may be helpful.

You may also want to look at the highly-customizable [Arch Linux](http://www.archlinux.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think such a distribution currently exists, but you could make one with the numerous tools available. Any one of the tiny distributions such as DSL can be fitted with a remote desktop client.

> what I means is have Linux that boots
>   up and is only a RDPclient nothing
>   else, like no desktop etc.

If you want graphics you'll have to have X installed at minimum.

Check out this other Superuser question "[Easiest linux distro creation](https://superuser.com/questions/87462/easiest-linux-distro-creation)" for information on how to roll your own.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://pctsc.ponderworthy.org

It's exactly what you asked for :-)

Comment: That website just goes to some music thing from Kansas...